# How to pass the sender and the arguments of event to the invoked command in ViewModel

Tags: xaml, mvvm, uwp, windows-10, mvvm-light

In my UWP Windows 10 app I want to clean my code-behind from events and other stuff and do everything in the ViewModel, so I use Core:InvokeCommandAction to invoke a command in the VM, but I don't know how to pass it the sender and the arguments for the Navigated event of the Frame object

```
<Frame x:Name="MyFrame" SourcePageType="{Binding MainFramePageType, Mode=TwoWay}">
    <Interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
        <Core:EventTriggerBehavior EventName="Navigated">
            <Core:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding MyFrameNavigatedCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=MyFrame}"/>            
        </Core:EventTriggerBehavior>
    </Interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
</Frame>
```

in the VM:

```
public RelayCommand<object> MyFrameNavigatedCommand { get; private set; }

...
MyFrameNavigatedCommand = new RelayCommand<object>(MyNavigatedCommandExecuted);
...

private void MyNavigatedCommandExecuted(object sender)
{
    (sender as Frame).BackStack.Clear();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`EventTriggerBehavior` passes the `EventArgs` object to each action, so for an `InvokeCommandAction` you just need the bound command to accept the parameter in your command implementation. I'm not 100% familiar with MVVMLight, but you're probably using some sort of "delegate command" implementation; just make sure your delegate has a parameter and you're all good.

If you need the `sender` argument too, then that's probably an indication that you should not be doing whatever it is you need to do with it in the view model (accessing/modifying the view directly is not the role of the view model). Nevertheless, it is possible to pass the sender argument too if you use `x:Bind` to bind the event to your view model instead of `EventTriggerBehavior` (`x:Bind` requires anniversary update SDK).

**XAML**

```
<Frame x:Name="MyFrame"
       SourcePageType="{Binding MainFramePageType, Mode=TwoWay}"
       Navigated="{x:Bind Vm.Navigated}"/>
```

**Code behind**

```
public MyViewModel Vm => (MyViewModel)DataContext;
```

**View model**

```
public void Navigated(object sender, NavigationEventArgs e)
{
}
```

Alternatively you can keep what you have already but just expose a `Frame` property on your view model which you can set in your page's code behind.

Based on the code you provided, if all you want to do is to clear the frame's back stack (or whatever) when the frame has navigated, then you can put this into your own custom behavior or attached property to handle view-specific things instead.

Comment: I figured it out about the sender, but how to pass the event args too? I also found out that if you don't specify CommandParameter, the EventArgs are being sent. Is there acutally a way to send both the sender object and the event arguments?

Comment: Sorry I missed the "sender" part of your question for some reason. See my edit.

Comment: I need one last clarification for best practices. So leaving CommandParameter empty, passes the EventArgs to the command and adding the Frame to the CommandParameter passes the object to the command (if expected). Naturally, InvokeCommandAction is not meant to send them both at the same time, so my question is what is best practice of them two (I suppose leaving CommandParameter empty, because it's natural obviously) in terms of not exposing the ViewModel to the View's logic, making anti patterns. As I figured it's not that bad to have some events logic in the code-behind, how to decide what?

Comment: If you do not set the CommandParameter, then it will inherit the value from the behavior which, for an EventTriggerBehavior, will be the EventArgs object for the event. You can only pass one thing to the command. The "proper" way is to not pass views to the view model at all as I suggested. Have you considered MVVMLight's navigation service instead for what you want to do here?